# Using SQL "IN" Function in Excel

Tags: excel

Is there an "IN" type function like the one used in sql that can be used in excel? For example, if i am writing an If statement in excel and I want it to check the contents of a cell for 5 different words can i write something like:

```
=If(A1=IN("word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"),"YES","NO")
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could use MATCH :

```
=MATCH(A1, {"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"}, 0)
```

which will return the index of the matching item in the array list. The trailing 0 means it should be an exact match. It will return #N/A if it isn't there, so you can tag a `IF(ISNA(` onto the front to make it behave like your "IN":

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1, {"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"}, 0)),"NO","YES")
```

Note the change in order of the `"YES"` and `"NO"`

Comment: if the range isn't static like you have it typed, but is a range of cells on the sheet, you could use VLOOKUP as an alternative.

Answer (score 24):

```
=IF(OR(A1={"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"}),"YES","NO")
```

Comment: Never mind. I've just found it works. -- Just remember to use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when finish editing the cell.

Comment: This is better for me than the accepted answer because it doesn't require ISNA().

Answer (score 1):

I think an improvement on

```
=IF(OR(A1={"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"}),"YES","NO")
```

would be to use

```
=IF(OR(A1={"word1","word2","word3","word4","word5"}),A1,"NO");
```

which is more like the SQL's `IN` clause.

Answer (score -2):

Use the OR function. It operationes very similiar to what you are looking for.

IF(OR(A1="word1",A1="word2",A1="word3")=TRUE,"Yes","No")

Also doesn't require the ctrl+shift+enter when using.