# in excel or google sheets, is there an 'if' function equivalent to the sql 'when A in (X,Y,Z)

Tags: sql, google-sheets, excel-formula

In excel or google sheets, is there an 'if' function equivalent to the sql 'when A in (X,Y,Z).  Currently I use: if(and(A=X, A=Y, A=Z), then, else).  Wondering if there is an: if(in(X,Y,Z)=A, then, else).

Thanks

Comment: Are a b and c constant or cell references?

Comment: Something along the line of `If(IsError(Match(A, {X,Y,Z},0)), else, then)`

Comment: Or have a look at these answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618168/using-sql-in-function-in-excel

Answer (score 2):

Just updating the answers [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618168/using-sql-in-function-in-excelhttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618168/using-sql-in-function-in-excel) slightly, for Excel and Google Sheets

```
=IF(OR(A1={1,2,3,4,5}),"Yes","No")
```

or

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1,{1,2,3,4,5},0)),"Yes","No")
```

For Open Office

```
=IF(OR(A1={1;2;3;4;5});"Yes";"No")
```

or

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(A1;{1;2;3;4;5};0));"Yes";"No")
```