# Using SQL "IN" function in Excel but with a column

Tags: excel

What I have :

- A table with columns (the column number has non unique numbers)
- Some numbers, but don't mind this, it is only because I wanted a spilled list
- A spilled list on F3 (the filter list), of any lenght

[image]

What I want :

- A Result table that only shows the rows whose number is in the spilled list.

Currently, the formula I used in Result table is :

```
=FILTER(Table1;(Table1[Number]=F3)+(Table1[Number]=F4))
```

The problem is that I need the spilled list to be as long as 10 or 20 cells, so my idea was not very efficient.

I tried `=FILTER(Table1;(Table1[Number]=F3#))` but this doesn't work.
(I thought about SQL "IN" function, because if I could try for each cell of the column if it is IN the list, it would work?)

I also tried `=XLOOKUP(F3#;Table1[Number];Table1)` but it gives me only Bob and Billy, not Martin even though Martin has number 1 (I think because XLOOKUP only shows the first match for each value).

[Using SQL "IN" Function in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618168/using-sql-in-function-in-excel) don't work for what I want (because only I have a column and not just 1 cell).

Thank you very much for your time, if you need any additionnal information please ask !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New answer based on updated information. Turns out you were on the right lines with `Filter` originally, just needed to use an `IF()` in that second argument. Try

```
=FILTER(Table1,IF(COUNTIF(F3#,Table1[Number])>0,TRUE,FALSE))
```

and let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use Vlookup - `VLOOKUP(F3#, Table1, 2, FALSE)` and let it spill next to your F3# spill range. Edit the 2 in the formula appropriate to tables in your column, and you'll need a separate spilling Vlookup formula for each column you want to return.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I just tried this formula, but I only get "#N/A". Does it work for you ? I also tried with XLOOKUP, but I can't get it done

Comment: It worked fine for me, what did you try with your XLOOKUP formula? Could you try an XLOOKUP and put something in the `if_not_found` parameter to check whether it's not finding the values or if the error is something different?

Comment: Hello, the thing is that VLOOKUP and XLOOKUP can match only 1 result per search value, so it returns only 1 row corresponding to number 1 and 1 row for number 3, even if I have 2 number 1. (for example, `XLOOKUP(1;Table1[Number];Table1[Firstname])` returns only Bob, but i want it to return both Bob and Martin, since they are both number 1). Do you have any idea on how to handle this ? Thanks so much for your time !

Comment: Ah, I was working on the assumption that your IDs were unique. I'm afraid non-unique IDs would require a bit of a different approach, I'll try and work it out and post as a separate answer if I get anywhere.

Comment: Oh, thanks so much ! Yes you're right, I'll add that my IDs are not unique in the description. Tell me if you need some more details !